# Can I connect the primary of two coupled inductors (transformer) directly to mains voltage in parallel or do I need intermediary circuitary?

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, inductor, mains, pspice

Examining a voltage regulator schematic, I believe I can connect the primary side of a step down transformer to mains voltage directly to step it down on the secondary, but PSpice doesn't let me simulate that same exact circuit(transformer with bridge rectifier) claiming I can't have a voltage source and inductor loop without a series resistor to break it. I don't know if this is just a PSpice limitation or if connecting the primary of a transformer directly to mains without resistors is a bad idea?

In PSpice, the two inductors are coupled using Place->PSpice Component->Passive->Coupling.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Background: The goal is to rebuild a voltage regulator using discrete components. I am trying to go from a 120 V 60 Hz to 12 Volts. Once I can step down and clip the negative wave correctly, I'll add the capacitive filter to smoothify or make the waveform more DC like.

Comment: You should probably at least have a fuse in series with the 230V side of the transformer so you don't start a fire if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't know if this is just a PSpice limitation or if connecting the
>   primary of a transformer directly to mains without resistors is a bad
>   idea?*

Put a 1 milli ohm resistor in series to break apart the inductor and the pure voltage source. It's a common enough trick to have to do on nearly all simulators.

The thing is this: a pure voltage source doesn't exist so it's no big deal adding the resistor like everyone else. Make it 1 micro-ohm if you want or a pico ohm. Even try 0 ohms - sometimes that works.

But, as per the comment by @user4574, the real circuit needs a fuse to protect the wiring infra-structure in the building.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Totally agree about the fuse as well.

Comment: Also take note what Spehro said about the peak voltage of 120 volts RMS being \$\sqrt2\$ higher - you need to set the peak voltage in a SPICE voltage source.

Comment: Yes, inductors and voltage sources are ideally zero resistance, so cause the simulator to fail, but in reality are small resistance, so you should put a sniff of R in there anyway. I often get bitten with 'floating node' when I use transmission lines for much the same reason, a parallel 100M makes the simulator happy.

Answer (score 0):

A real transformer will have a resistance of perhaps hundreds of ohms on the primary and tens of ohms on the secondary so your transformer model should reflect that.

You should have a fuse as noted in the comments, in a real circuit, and that fuse will have a bit of resistance.

Your voltage source appears to be incorrect- SPICE voltage sources are specified in terms of peak voltage and your mains is specified in terms of RMS, so you'd want \$\sqrt{2}\$ larger voltage to model what comes out of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if this is just a PSpice limitation

Yes and no.  PSpice simulates *ideal* circuit elements.  That's "ideal" as in Platonic, unreachable, unreal circuits.  I'm not sure what sort of analysis you're doing, but PSpice should do transient analysis just fine; it's probably unhappy about finding the DC operating point.

At any rate, the expected behavior of a simulator is to simulate ideal components, because no one knows to what level of accuracy *your* simulation requires, and *how* it can be ideal or how it needs to model reality more closely.

So your job, when using a simulator like PSpice, is to know how *real* components differ from ideal.  When you're lucky, this means modeling those real components as collections of ideal components.  Typically, for a transformer this means modeling the primary and secondary resistances, and the leakage inductance (by using a coupling factor that's less than unity).  When you're not lucky, it means writing a nonlinear model by hand, or making up a circuit with amplifiers and diodes and such (essentially making an analog computer) that does the heavy lifting.